# How to generate a "onNOmousemove" Event with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jquery-events

I played around with a webdesign where jQuery is available. There is now a point where I need the opposite Eventwatching, so I realized it already with a jQuery routine which installs an `"onnomousemove"` event. Yes, you read correct, an `NOT HAPPENING EVENT`.

(*Below*) you find my allready working solution in jQuery.
 The idea is to have **control over not happening Events** and to react on that via this extra specified [`jQuery.Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Hehe, I know most stupid would be to handle `"onnoerror"` Events with this. But thats not desired. Its working now and I want to go a step forward here. So what is my problem?

**Here it comes:** How to fire the same behavior with `native Javascript EventListening` so `element.addEventListener(...);` can handle the same Events too?

**Problem:** newer Web browser like Chrome, Firefox have an implemented `CustomEvent` handling to make this happen, but in older browsers there should be a way with prototype or so.
I'm a bit jQuery blind now, anyway is there somebody out there who knows the freaky trick to generate Custom Events in a traditional way **without** prototype.js or other libraries? Even a solution with jQuery would be fine, but desired goal is the native listener should be able to handle it.

jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        // extends jQuery with the opposite Event Listener
        onno:function(eventname,t,fn){
            var onnotimer = null;
            var jqueryevent = {};
            $(this).on( eventname, function(e){
                window.clearTimeout(onnotimer);
                function OnNoEventFn(){
                    jqueryevent = jQuery.Event( "onno"+eventname );
                    $(this).trigger(jqueryevent);
                    e.timeStampVision=e.timeStamp+t;
                    e.timer=t; e.type="onno"+eventname;
                    fn(e);
                }
                onnotimer = window.setTimeout( OnNoEventFn, t);
            });
            return $(this);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    // installs "onnomousemove" and fires after 5sec if mousemove does not happen.
    $(window).onno('mousemove', 5000, function(e){
        console.log('function fires after:'+e.timer+'ms at:'+e.timeStampVision+'ms with:"'+e.type+'" event, exact fired:', e.timeStamp);
    });
    // installs "onnoclick" and fires after 4sec if click does not happen.
    $(window).onno('click', 4000, function(e){
        console.log('function fires after:'+e.timer+'ms at:'+e.timeStampVision+'ms with:"'+e.type+'" event, exact fired:', e.timeStamp);
    });
    
    // just for demonstration, routine with "onno.." eventnamescheme
    $(window).on('onnomousemove',function(e){
        console.log( 'tadaaaa: "'+e.type+'" works! with jQuery Event',e);
    });
    // same for "onnoclick"
    $(window).on('onnoclick',function(e){
        console.log( 'tadaaaa: "'+e.type+'" works! with jQuery Event',e);
    });
});

// but how to install Custom Events even in older Safari ?
// newer Chrome, Firefox & Opera have CustomEvent.
window.addEventListener('onnomousemove',function(e){
    console.log('native js is watching you',e);
},false);
```

Comment: If using `CustomEvent()` is too new for the browsers you want to support, the out of date way to do it is [explained at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Creating_and_triggering_events)...

Comment: thank you, will try now. until then, something to play http://tinker.io/a2420/4

Comment: works just fine, nice tip. now i recognize also touchpad two finger scroll (which produces no mousemove) is firing events on mousemove, is that right? oops!

Comment: arrrgh! nope, was not wrong, mousemove is fired because it starts scrolling the page, which is a relative mousemove to page offsetY.